# How do I improve workflow when switching between programming on Ubuntu and Adobe apps on Windows?

Tags: adobe

I constantly reboot between Adobe and Ubuntu when I need to so dome graphic design and UI work. Or should I just switch to a Mac? Is it possible to have Adobe on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a dual boot?

Install virtualbox, install Windows inside virtualbox, install adobe inside windows inside virtualbox. Set up virtualbox with things like guest additions.

And you can use adobe while using Ubuntu at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Now i'm trying to learn how to install virtualbox and how to use it.